# Text in span not displayed where it should

Tags: html, css

i have the following html:

```
<div class="quickselect">
        <div class="middle">
            <label class="label_quickselect">
                <input class="input_quickselect" type="radio" name="qty" value="1" checked/>
                <div class="quantity box">
                    <span>1X</span>
                </div>
            </label>

            <label class="label_quickselect">
                <input class="input_quickselect" type="radio" name="qty" value="2"/>
                <div class="quantity box">
                    <span>2X</span>
                </div>
            </label>
            <label class="label_quickselect">
                <input class="input_quickselect" type="radio" name="qty" value="3"/>
                <div class="quantity box">
                    <span>3X</span>
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the corresponding css:

```
.middle {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
  }
  .middle .input_quickselect {
    display: none;
  }
  .middle .input_quickselect:checked + .box {
    background-color: white;
  }
  .middle .input_quickselect:checked + .box span {
    color: black;
    transform: translateY(70px);
  }
  .middle .input_quickselect:checked + .box span:before {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .middle .box {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    transition: all 250ms ease;
    will-change: transition;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid black;
    font-family: "sans-serif", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
  }
  .middle .box:active {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  .middle .box span {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate(0, 60px);
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 20%;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    user-select: none;
    color: black;
  }
  .middle .box span:before {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: block;
    transform: translateY(-80px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: black;
  }
```

So the radio buttons are styled as box with a nice animation on click.
Unfortunately, the text of the active button (the span) is not displayed, as supposed to be, in the center of the button, instead it is way below the button.
Can anyone help me there?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/hj2o6kra  If you toss it in a fiddle - it seems pretty good. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @ItFreak, couldn't find an any issue here.Please explain.

Comment: I think you're confusing things with the number of translateY transitions. It's slightly unclear what the desired effect is. Have a look at this (adjusted) fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f1nadxtg/ , it may help you.

Comment: @RachelGallen thank you for the advice and fiddle, it was indeed a  problem with one of the translate() functions. Failure is explained in the answer below

Comment: @ItFreak well done for finding the solution :)

Comment: @RachelGallen haha no problem :D

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was indeed a translate() function:

```
  .middle .input_quickselect:checked + .box span {
    color: black;
    transform: translateY(70px);
  }
```

caused the span to move down by 70 pixels.
Thanks to Rachel Gallen.